# Make a synchronized new for Modules in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I use node.js and I write this code:

```
const Matrix  = require('./src/matrix/matrix');
var matrix1 = new Matrix("input1.dat","input2.dat");
var matrix2 = new Matrix("input1.dat","input2.dat");
```

They make new for both matrix variables at the same Time, but I need to make new for matrix2 after matrix1 is finished

Comment: `matrix2` *is* created after `matrix1` is done. It can't be created before then. If you are loading files asynchronously then `matrix1` may not be completely initialized but it will exist.

Comment: How is `Matrix` defined?

Comment: @ Mike C  Hi Mike. Yes I read the files asynchronously. But also If I write this Code: 

var matrix1 = new Matrix("input/input_vertex.dat","input/input_edge.dat")
matrix.dim;

They told me dim in not defined, although I return it.

Comment: @AbdulAzizSabra The asynchronous stuff is what matters. You can't just tell the engine to stop and wait for an asynchronous function call to finish. You need to either handle that with a callback or a promise.

Comment: @ Frxstrem I wirte this thing: 
 module.exports = function (file1, file2){
   return {
  }
}

Comment: @Mike C but Mike in the secode code example I make only new for object. I thing this thing should be synchronous

Comment: @AbdulAzizSabra Are you or are you not loading in data asynchronously during the construction of a `Matrix` object?

Comment: @Mike C I loaded asynchronously.

Comment: @AbdulAzizSabra Then that it your problem. If your code is asynchronous then the rest of your code is going to run before your asynchronous code complete. You need to hook in to this completion with either a callback or a Promise.

Comment: @ Mike C ok thank you Mike.